# How to customize pull swipe to refresh layout androidx ? without using any library

Tags: android

i want to implement custom pull to refresh like attached image displaying pull to refresh text with down arrow in white rectangular area.

[image: I want to use image and text in place of default progress style of swipe to refresh layout as displayed in image.]

I went through previous solution which is not needful at all and not getting any needful third party library.

Comment: because i am not getting for what i am looking .. which i explained as well . nothing else . and  checking lots of example too but i am not getting my solution ....

Comment: i need to customize only SwipeToRefresh layout using any method or any library but first i am trying to ignore third parties library . but if will not get any option of customization then have to go with third party library.

Comment: ohh yhh that question is also unanswered mean don't have solution so say simply no solution ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't get answer from any one but after many tries i got a library using which i can customize swipe to refresh layout as per requirement.

implementation 'com.reginald.swiperefresh:library:1.1.2'

for more details or example you can get my implemented example from git.

https://github.com/AnkuKmrRoy/MyCustomPullToRefreshApplication